# https and http alternating on HTML forms every other git push (and post-receive git checkout -f)

Tags: git, https, git-push, git-checkout, git-post-receive

I have a web site that is using Laravel and using Git to push changes from my local laptop to Live (apache) web server.  The server runs as a VPS.

I have an issue that seems to be occuring consistently with every other Git push.  With web pages that contain forms that require SSL/HTTPS connectivity I have noticed the following:

- when I push a change via Git, the HTML web page shows as "https" as the form action.
- when I push the same file via Git again (with trivial change, same code), the HTML web page shows "http" as the form action and a warning is visible using Fire bug as follows:
  "Password fields present in a form with an insecure (http://) form action.
- when i push again, the form action is "https" again without the error.
- I can ftp the file as many times as I like and each time the form action is as expected, i.e. is "https".

I have no idea why this is happening and would be extremely grateful if someone could shed light on the possible cause of this.

Comment: This is very strange. Are you using a hook or something to trigger a build process during the deployment?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes it is very strange indeed. I am totally confused as to why this is happening.  I am performing a git push as follows: "git push origin master" using SSH key. I have created a simple hook called post-receive which contains the lines: #!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=~ git checkout -f

Comment: Could it be the version of PHP?  We were using 5.4.11 before and are now using 5.4.23.

Comment: could it also be due to the fact that the user does not have the right permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple in the end.  Under storage\views (in the Laravel framework) were old files that just had to be deleted.

It became more obvious when my front page had different text despite the web directory containing the correct file.